# Understanding TUN interface in VPN in OpenWRT/LEDE

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openwrt

I'm currently playing around with VPNs and router Firmware. I managed to properly install and configure my VPN on my LEDE router, however I'm not sure if the traffic is actually routed as it's supposed to be.

Here is a screenshot after boot:
[LEDE Interface section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUlJj.png)

I see that on my WAN interface there is more traffic than on the TUN interface. Is that supposed to be that way? Why is that the case, I thought all traffic was passed through the TUN - link before?
Whenever I use `traceroute` on Debian or try to track myself with ipleak.net, dnsleaktest.net etcetc. I see no trace from my location, however this puzzles me a little bit. Maybe I just don't fully understand the function of the TUN interface yet.

A little clarification would be great!

PS.: The difference on the picture only grows when the time goes on.

Comment: See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46442/openvpn-tap-vs-tun-mode) for details relating to TAP vs TUN, the two modes OpenVPN use for connecting

Comment: The screenshot shows no information about your actual routing configuration, or what is connected to what. Regardless, there's a dozen of reasons you'd see differing amounts of traffic on the two interfaces, and far too many variables for it to even be relevant. What's your actual question, other than "Why is there more traffic on one interface than another" which is unanswerable.

Comment: Do you need more information? If yes, which one?

Comment: There must be *at least* as much traffic on the WAN interface as on the TUN interface, because every packet sent through the TUN interface is wrapped up and tunneled to the other endpoint, using the WAN interface.

Comment: Yes, that's true. After three days of uptime, I have RX/TX 16/3 GB on WAN and 0.6/2 GB on TUN. That's... really small. I'm curious what's not working right here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is related to the vpn's encryption, the encrypted data taking more space than the plain data.

Would you share your routing setup ?

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Sure, there you go: https://ibb.co/e0bJQ6